# Is there a way to save profiles on Motorola's Droid X?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, profiles, wallpaper

When I had an HTC Eris I could change "profiles".  Each profile was basically:  wallpaper + screen lock image + all apps on your desktop.  So, I could have a work profile that had my apps that were geared for while I was at work, a social profile to switch my phone to having FB, Twitter, etc on my desktop with a different wallpaper, etc.

Is there an app for that?  ;)

Comment: Note: This looks like it is popping up as a feature in Gingerbread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're referring to are called [HTC Scenes](http://www.htc.com/uk/howto.aspx?p_id=283&id=9&page=3) (Hero Scenes link).  Off the top of my head I don't know of anything like that and only HTC devices have the HTC Scenes.

I just did a quick search of the market and didn't come up with anything so my initial guess is:

**No, there is nothing like that currently.** You would either need a Sense-based custom ROM (not sure if there are any for the Droid X) or an HTC device.

Comment: well....  shoot!